# Using jq in a bash script to get an element with a certain value pattern

Tags: bash, shell-script, jq, homebrew

I'm calling the homebrew api in a shell script with the goal of getting the App name for the item before trying to install it. Luckily the api provides this in an element called `artifacts`. Unluckily, `artifacts` does not have further keys to just select one element. It can be a mixture of objects and arrays in arbitrary order.

Example data snippet for Google Chrome:

```
{
   "name":[
      "Google Chrome"
   ],
   "artifacts":[
      [
         "Google Chrome.app"
      ]
   ]
}
```

But docker is a different story:

```
{
   "name":[
      "Docker"
   ],
   "artifacts":[
       {
         "trash":[
           "$(brew --prefix)/bin/docker-compose.backup",
           "$(brew --prefix)/bin/docker.backup"
         ]
      },
      [
         "docker.app"
      ]
   ]
}
```

So I can't just get element 0 from `artifacts` in my shell script like so.

```
artifacts=$(curl -s "https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask/google-chrome.json" | jq -r '.artifacts[0][0]')
```

Is there a way to use jq to search values in the `artifacts` element for the pattern that ENDS with *.app? Best psuedo code I can come up with is this, but I'm getting into a bit of a mess trying to reference $element

```
# $cask is determined by a list the script loops through ('google-chrome' is one example)
for element in $(curl -s "https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask/$cask.json" | jq -r '.artifacts'); do
    # if $element is an array and it's value ends with "*.app"
        # assign to a variable for later use
done
```

Here is a [jqplay snippet](https://jqplay.org/s/4W-qjCdDEm_s) of one of the more complex JSON returns. You will see a single array part way down with the sole value "docker.app". That's what I want to target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A similar query [as what muru has](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/707671/116858), but returns all artefacts in any `artifacts` array if any of the entries in the array ends with the string `.app`:

```
.artifacts[] | select(type == "array" and any(endswith(".app")))[]
```

or,

```
.artifacts[] | arrays | select(any(endswith(".app")))[]
```

So if an application has some artefact `thething.app` *and* `someotherthing.quux` in the same array, then both are returned.

Answer (score 4):

This `jq` query works for me with the JSON for Docker:

```
.artifacts[] | arrays[0] | select(endswith(".app"))
```

The `arrays` filter selects arrays from elements of `artifacts`, and then we can look for the first elements of these arrays for one which ends with `.app`.